# <unknown>:0: error: Opening import file for module 'Swift': Not a directory

Tags: swift

After changing my framework search path to $(inherited) so that the cocoapods framework search path could be used I came up with this error. I also recently changed the name of my project to try to keep things more organized. I am fairly new to Xcode and have no clue how to even approach this problem.

Comment: You should give more informations about your problem, it seems to me as it the question is to vague to be answered.